# Reset a css property on :hover

Tags: html, css, svg, hover

I'm using svg to embed stack overflow's logo into my resume. The svg xml contains the fill color of the logo.

Here is the svg content

```
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64" id="svg3715">
<defs id="defs3717"/>
<g id="layer1">
<path d="m 9.3049611,36.847632 4.4013079,0.04316 -0.153442,19.598393 29.291259,0 0,-19.527506 4.637782,0 0,24.287331 -38.2006795,0 0.023777,-24.401371 z" id="path2830" fill="#919191" style="fill-opacity:1;stroke:none"/>
<rect width="22.944817" height="4.881876" x="16.481951" y="48.434078" id="rect3604" fill="#919191" style="fill-opacity:1;stroke:none"/>
<rect width="23.066864" height="5.0039229" x="20.749949" y="37.830307" transform="matrix(0.9953749,0.09606666,-0.09606666,0.9953749,0,0)" id="rect3606" fill="#A78B68" style="fill-opacity:1;stroke:none"/>
<rect width="23.066864" height="5.0039229" x="26.472515" y="23.401554" transform="matrix(0.96240291,0.27162592,-0.27162592,0.96240291,0,0)" id="rect3606-1" fill="#c19653" style="fill-opacity:1;stroke:none"/>
<rect width="23.066864" height="5.0039229" x="30.528769" y="3.1535864" transform="matrix(0.85597805,0.51701216,-0.51701216,0.85597805,0,0)" id="rect3606-1-3" fill="#D48C28" style="fill-opacity:1;stroke:none"/>
<rect width="23.066864" height="5.0039229" x="27.191883" y="-24.475019" transform="matrix(0.58242689,0.81288309,-0.81288309,0.58242689,0,0)" id="rect3606-1-3-7" fill="#FE8908" style="fill-opacity:1;stroke:none"/>
<rect width="23.066864" height="5.0039229" x="11.174569" y="-50.183693" transform="matrix(0.16480989,0.98632535,-0.98632535,0.16480989,0,0)" id="rect3606-1-3-7-6" fill="#FF7A15" style="fill-opacity:1;stroke:none"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

I can set the logo to be black (what I want it to look like on normal state) using

```
rect, path
{
    fill: black;
}
```

But now, what can I do to *remove* the property on `:hover`, in order to have the logo find back it's brightness ?

I tried to look on the `fill` parameters [documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/painting.html#SpecifyingPaint). But I found nothing helping.

Comment: What do you mean by removing the property? You can set fill to none :) I also did not understand the part about "[...] find back it's brightness"

Comment: Tried `rect:hover, path:hover { fill: none; }` ?

Comment: I think I know what the OP means - he wants the logo colors to return after hovering out.

Comment: @Terry This is exactly what I meant.

Comment: @m.spyratos `fill: none` removes every color informations.

Comment: @TomAhh, Just a guess! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible - simply use the `:not()` selector in CSS. Some browsers might not support it though:

```
svg:not(:hover) rect,
svg:not(:hover) path {
    fill: black;
}
```

See fiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/qvV8Q/

[Edit]: For the sake of completeness - should you want to add compatibility for browsers that do not support the `:not()` selector, you simply toggle a `.hover` class and style accordingly:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("svg").hover(function() {
        $(this).attr("class", "hover");
    }, function() {
        $(this).attr("class", "");
    });
});
```

**Note**: The reason why `.attr()` is used is because the add/removeClass method does not work with `<svg>` elements natively. However, this can be remedied by using this plugin - http://keith-wood.name/svg.html#dom

And the CSS:

```
.hover rect, .hover path {
    fill: black;
}
```

The JS-powered alternative can be viewed here - http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/LTRCB/